# PhoneScreen problems with incoming call

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde

I want to add a field to the Phone Screen when a screen is received. I successfully made this using the following code:

```
public void callIncoming(int callId) {
    PhoneScreen ps = new PhoneScreen(Call, UiApplication.getApplication());
    PhoneScreenHorizontalManager manager = new PhoneScreenHorizontalManager();
    LabelField label = new LabelField("Call Received");
    manager.add(label);
    ps.add(manager);
    ps.setScreenBackground(Color.RED);
    ps.sendDataToScreen();
}
```

I tried this code on the following devices:
BB Mini Curve, Bold 4, Bold 2 and Curve and this works like a charm with all the functionality I want. A background colored red is appearing in the area where I can draw fields

I tried it on these phones and the label field did not appear: Torch, Bold3

On these phones, When I add data to the screen, I guess that these fields are appearing below the ringer off notification. With these devices, no Background is appearing... So this is a main issue.

How to solve this and make the fields appear on these phones too?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer, but have started a thread here:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/PhoneScreenDemo-not-displaying-information-on-os6/m-p/1450769#M184811

I've opened a RIM ticket and will share info as I get it.

As far as I can see PhoneScreen has big issues and is not consistently supported across devices.

Using isSupported() will only determine if the device screen type supports the API, (SVG is required according to RIM Jira ticket), not if it will actually work.